# Define variable in variable/parameter and use in javascript?

Tags: jquery, css, raphael

I want to defined a variable/parameter in CSS and access it by javascript. What is the best way of doing this?

One option I thought of would be to place a cutsom attribute on the `body` element, then access that attribute via jQuery.

A little more info: I'm defining colour sets in CSS. I've created a function with RaphaelJS to draw a gradient background on the page. I want this function to use a *highlight colour* (which is not used elsewhere on the DOM) which will be defined in the CSS along with the other colour elements.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a mock element using jQuery, assign the class `hightlightColour` to it, get any CSS definitions you might need and destroy the element.

```
$(function() {
    var highlightColour = getClassCSS('highlightColour', 'color');
    alert(highlightColour);
});

function getClassCSS(className, attribute) {
    var mock = $('<div />').addClass(className).appendTo('body');
    var value = mock.css(attribute);
    mock.remove();
    return value;
}
```

That snippet would get the `color` attribute that is defined for the `highlightColour` class in CSS. Just make sure there's nothing overwriting the attributes. Tested and working on Firefox 3.6.

Comment: this doesn't work, as is, because `mock` will only take on the properties when attached to the DOM. (tested safari).

Comment: @Ross, you're right, you need to attach the element to the DOM first. I've updated my answer.